# How to compile scipy.interp1d into tensorflow?2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

I’m trying to use a neural network to fit the solution of equation:

[image: govern equation]

Which has analytic solution:

[image: analytic solution]

I want to express ***y*** as a constrained form:

[image: constrained form]

Where ***u1*** is a function that satisfy the boundary constraint **y=0.1 at x=0 and 1**

***u2*** is a function that satisfy the zero boundary constraint ***y=0  at x=0 and 1***

[image: neural network] is my neural network.

when i choose u1 and u2 as a simple function and define my loss function as:

```
class GradMseLoss(Loss, ABC):
    # ini_x represents coordinate of gradient calculation, rdp is the coordinate used for the govern equation calculation
def __init__(self, in_x, rdp, model, name='custom'):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.in_x = in_x
        self.rdp = rdp
        self.model = model

    def custom_func(self, coord_pos):
         f_one = tf.add(tf.multiply(tf.square(coord_pos), tf.add(coord_pos, -1.)), 0.1)
         f_two = tf.multiply(coord_pos, tf.add(coord_pos, -1.))
         final_out = tf.add(f_one, f_two * self.model(coord_pos))
         return final_out

    def grad(self, pos):
          ...
        return udv_loss

    def govern_equation(self, poi):
         ...
        return rdp_loss

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        udv_loss = self.grad(self.in_x)
        rdp_loss = self.govern_equation(self.rdp)

        first_part = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(udv_loss))
        second_part = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(rdp_loss))
        third_part = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square((y_true - y_pred)))

        loss =first_part + second_part + third_part
        return loss
```

the neural  network converge fast and end with the right solution.

but when i change ***u1 and u2*** as the interpolation function which were obtained by scipy.inerpld(the data is the same as the above mentioned function). i have to convert it to a tensorflow function. online information indicates that i colud use ***tf.numpy_function*** to achieve my goal. as i tried to change my code as:

```
class GradMseLoss(Loss, ABC):
    # ini_x represents coordinate of gradient calculation, rdp is the coordinate used for the govern equation calculation
def __init__(self, in_x, rdp, model, interp_x, interp_y_u1, interp_y_u2, name='custom'):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.in_x = in_x
        self.rdp = rdp
        self.model = model

        self.interp_x = interp_x
        self.interp_by = interp_by
        self.interp_cy = interp_cy

        self.fb = interp1d(self.interp_x, self.interp_by, kind=2)
        self.fc = interp1d(self.interp_x, self.interp_cy, kind=2)

    def num_bound_func(self, in_num):
        return np.dot(1., self.fb(in_num)).astype(np.float32)

    def num_coe_func(self, in_num_c):
        return np.dot(1., self.fc(in_num_c)).astype(np.float32)

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(None, tf.float32)])
    def tf_bound_func(self, aks_inp_b):
        return tf.numpy_function(self.num_bound_func, [aks_inp_b], tf.float32)

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(None, tf.float32)])
    def tf_coe_func(self, aks_inp_c):
        return tf.numpy_function(self.num_coe_func, [aks_inp_c], tf.float32)

    def custom_func(self, coord_pos):
        f_one = tf.cast(self.tf_bound_func(coord_pos), dtype=tf.float32)
        f_two = tf.cast(self.tf_coe_func(coord_pos), dtype=tf.float32)
        final_out = tf.add(f_one, f_two * self.model(coord_pos))
        return final_out


    def grad(self, pos):
        ...
        return udv_loss

    def govern_equation(self, poi):
        ...
        return rdp_loss

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        udv_loss = self.grad(self.in_x)
        rdp_loss = self.govern_equation(self.rdp)

        first_part = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(udv_loss))
        second_part = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(rdp_loss))
        third_part = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square((y_true - y_pred)))

        loss =first_part + second_part + third_part
        return loss
```

there is no error information, but the neural network can not converge, which indicates that there is a data transport problem. i also tried ***tf.py_func, tf.map_fn,*** they don't work.

so, i wanna know what is the problem of my code? how can i fix it? thanks!!!